# Updating React attributes as state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a bracket generator app. I am hitting a state management issue where I am trying to access some data from a child component using attributes (basically I want to push data up the React tree but this isn't allowed).

At a high level,  I am combining small `BracketMatchup` components to form a bracket. I should be able to pass two `id`s to this component to reference the previous matchups.

```
      <div className={styles.bracket}>
        <div className={styles.bracketColumn}>
          <BracketMatchup
            highseed={getTeam("Kansas")}
            lowseed={getTeam("ISU")}
            round={1}
            id="1"
          />
          <BracketMatchup
            highseed={getTeam("TCU")}
            lowseed={getTeam("BYU")}
            round={1}
            id="2"
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={styles.bracketColumn}
          style={{ marginTop: "calc(-75px / 2)" }}
        >
          <BracketMatchup
            highseed={getSeed("1")}
            lowseed={getSeed("2")}
            round={2}
            id="9"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

In this example we have two games in the first round (ids 1 and 2). I want my `getSeed` function to pull the winner from each of those games so that the `BracketMatchup` with `id=9` can pull this data.

What I am attempting to do is set the winner of each matchup as an attribute in the `BracketMatchup`.

```
export const BracketMatchup = ({ highseed, lowseed, side, round, id }) => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [teamPowerScore, setTeamPowerScore] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (highseed?.teamPowerScore > lowseed?.teamPowerScore) {
      setName(highseed?.name);
      setTeamPowerScore(highseed?.teamPowerScore);
    } else {
      setName(lowseed?.name);
      setTeamPowerScore(lowseed?.teamPowerScore);
    }
  }, [
    highseed?.teamPowerScore,
    lowseed?.teamPowerScore,
    highseed?.name,
    lowseed?.name,
  ]);

  return (
    <div
      className={style.bracketMatchup}
      style={{
        height: `calc(75px *  ${Math.pow(2, round - 1)})`,
        marginTop: `calc(75px * ${Math.pow(2, round - 1)}`,
      }}
    >
      <div className={style.highSeed}>{highseed?.name}</div>
      <div className={style.lowSeed}>{lowseed?.name}</div>
      <div
        id={id}
        name={name}
        teamPowerScore={teamPowerScore}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can see the bottom `div` with `display: none` is setting attributes with the projected winners data.

Now my `getSeed` function tries to pull this data.

```
  function getSeed(seed) {
    const seed1 = document.getElementById(seed);

    const name = seed1?.getAttribute("name");
    const teamPowerScore = seed1?.getAttribute("teamPowerScore");

    return { name: name, teamPowerScore: teamPowerScore };
  }
```

The function works well expect that it's data seems to lag behind the current state value as `teamPowerScore` changes.

I am open to different solutions. I could use context but I would need to manage a different value for each matchup.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dreamy-newton-99vgyy?file=%2Fsrc%2FBracketMatchup.js%3A36%2C7)

Comment: You are mixing presentation and data, defeating the whole purpose of React. Keep your data in some state, and pass it down accordingly.

Comment: I understand and agree with you.  However in this particular instance I would need state variables for 64 different matchups. Certainly doable but not ideal. A much simpler approach would be to return a value from each `BracketMatchup`. The attribute method I am using might not be ideal, but I think their is a better solution than storing all that data in a massive object.

Comment: Well you are still storing the same amount of data! You can still abstract it somewhere, and make `getSeed` pull it from somewhere else than the DOM (e.g. from a [context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)).

Comment: [This is a quick and dirty solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6xbx1x?file=src%2FApp.jsx) - the matchups are stored in an array of rounds, see the logs to grasp it better - hope it helps!